# JS webcomponent with external object

Tags: javascript, promise, web-component

I managed to implement a kind of infinite scroll on a table. Basically I only fetch the rows I need to display along with some extra cache ones. When I scroll I add some extra rows again to fill the gap.

I still need some adjustments but it works well. The problem now is that I need to implement the logic in several pages which requires lots of boiler plate.

I wonder if it this possible to encapsulate all the stuf in a webcomponent `virtual-table`. Is there a way to inject the content of the table from the controller?

```
var Content = class Content {
    
    // Models the table header, rows as well as methods to prepend or appends rows (when scrolling).
}
```

I try to use the controller name from the attribute and `fetch` the content, but the main issue I see comes from the `promise` which I don't seem the be able to pass to the content member of the class because of the asynchronicity. I initialy used an `async / await` method but I don't think it makes sense with webcomponent.

```
export default class VirtualTable extends HTMLElement {

    static get observedAttributes() {

        return ['controller'];
    }

    content = null;

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.content = this.getContent(0); // Returns null!
   }

   getContent(index) {

        var body = JSON.stringify({
            Index: index
        });

        // Gets the content from the controller.
        const fetchPromise = fetch(`${window.location.href}${this.controller}/GetContent/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        });
            
        fetchPromise.then((response) => {

            var jsonPromise = response.json();

            jsonPromise.then((json) => {

                return new Content(json); // Correctly instantiate the Content class.
            });
        });
    }
}
```

```
<body>

    <virtual-table controller="items">

    </virtual-table>

</body>

<script type="module">

    import VirtualTable from './scripts/VirtualTable.js'

    customElements.define('virtual-table', VirtualTable);

</script>
```

Does anyone have some insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async/await` makes for compacter code

Imported part is to **not** do DOM updates in the `constructor` phase;
only once the `connectedCallback` runs do you know the Elements are IN the DOM or can be added to the DOM

Since the `constructor` may not be `async` (needed for await), you can 't do the fetch there; you can resort to a promissed fetch.

The scroll part is up to you..

```js
customElements.define("json-table", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML =
    `<table><thead>`+
    `<tr><th>id</th><th>firstName</th><th>lastName</th></tr>`+
    `<thead>` +
    `<tbody></tbody>` +
    `</table>`;
    this.tbody = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("tbody");
  }
  async connectedCallback() {
    let json = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("endpoint"))).json();
    json.users.forEach(user => this.add(user));
  }
  add(user){
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = ["id","firstName","lastName"]
                        .map(key=>`<td>${user[key]}</td>`).join("");
    this.tbody.append(tr);  
  }
})
```

```html
<json-table endpoint='https://dummyjson.com/users' ></json-table>
```

And before you ask for `<slot>` elements inside `<table>` (which can't be done),
do read and understand: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/630

Comment: OK, thanks Danny! Everything seems to perfectly work.